# C++ reverse an iterator

Tags: c++

Is it possible to reverse an iterator in C++?

For instance, a lot of algorithms are designed on the principle that you pass the beginning and ending iterators:

```
template <typename T>
void func( Iterator begin, Iterator end ){
    ...
}
```

Now suppose that internally, I need to iterate forward and backward over the container:

```
template <typename T>
void func( Iterator begin, Iterator end ){
    // Iterate forward 
    ...
    // Iterate backward
    ...
}
```

I COULD certainly pass a negative value to `std::advance`. But I am wondering if it would instead be possible to just convert the iterators to reverse iterators. Is that possible?

Comment: The user would pass the reverse iterators to `func`.  Why would you need to change your function?

Comment: Sorry. I was not clear enough. Internally, I need to go forward and backward over the container.

Comment: Leave that to the user.  If the user wants to traverse "left to right, then right to left" or "right to left, then left-to-right", so be it.

Comment: Why don't you use some bidirectionnal operator as type of args?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just call [`std::make_reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_reverse_iterator) on the arguments to get a reverse view of the range. The cpp reference page has a demo. That is of course assuming reversal is possible.

Comment: Aha. I knew there would be something like this. I just couldn't find it.

Comment: This is a good answer (as you can expect from StoryTeller), but note, as he does, that this doesn't always work.

Comment: Also note that using class template argument deduction instead of the corresponding `make_*` function template saves typing 5 characters.

Answer (score 7):

No that is not possible in full generality. For example, consider a singly-linked list where you can only iterate in one direction (i.e. it is *Forward iterable* but not *Bidirectional iterable*).

A solution in your case would be for the caller of the function to pass reverse iterators.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges#Iterators

Comment: That is possible in general! If you can iterate in one direction then you can always iterate in the opposite: play recursively or build an iterator that at its construction iterates 'til the end in the natural direction and in its own iteration goes backwards over the elements stored at construction.

Comment: maybe: "it is not possible without imposing considerable overhead" ?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - How do you iterate an input stream in reverse? Or a forward list?

Comment: @StoryTeller eg you iterate forward and store the elements in a container that allows backward iteration

Comment: I'm not really sure that counts. At that point you're iterating backwards over the data, you're creating new data, and that's a whole different ballgame.

Comment: @user463035818 - Storing them aside creates a new range. It does not allow you to reverse iterate the same range, which is what I gathered the OP wants, and Bathsheba correctly explains about.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit From the external viewpoint it is exactly the same game, the user just wants to observe datas in a given order. The problem of storing the data internally is another one. One can't say "it is not reasonable in general" but not "it is impossible in general". Where it is stated that it is forbidden for an iterator to store something?

Comment: @Jean Your iterator isn't storing something, the algorithm is. I can't think of a reason for that to be forbidden, but I can think of plenty of reasons that you wouldn't want it to do that. Sure, you _could_ make algorithms copy all the data to an off-site server by carrier pigeon for acting on it by morse code over a dial-up modem, but that breaks the principle of least surprise and the performance will not be acceptable to anybody.

Comment: @StoryTeller The only problematic case is an infinite stream. If it is finite, then you can reverse (it is sufficient to temp-store the forwarding iteration).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - I have a feeling you just ignored everything  Lightness Races in Orbit and I said a moment ago.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then you agree on: one can say "it is not reasonable in general" but not "it is impossible in general". (sorry for my preceding comment can't -> can)

Comment: @storyteller I have the feeling you don't want to see that it is possible; but I agree this may not be reasonable to do so.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - Everything is "possible" if one ignores all constraints. But that leaves us with a very useless definition of "possible".

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Correct

Comment: @StoryTeller No! Not everything is possible, but that is. Now and again, making it in the general case may not be reasonable for various reasons. As the OP doesn't state anything about what he is iterating on, we can't say "it is not possible".

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: I was careful to add "in full generality" as you can come up with a scenario where it is not possible; something based on a stream of non-copyable values being a starting point. My feeling is that my answer stands correct as it is.

Comment: @StoryTeller As you proposed to make a reverse one, then you must agree because there is many cases in which it is reasonable.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - Of course, in the case of a bi-directional iterator it is quite reasonable. But I hope you noticed I added *"That is of course assuming reversal is possible"*.

Comment: @StoryTeller My last comment. I suppose "That is of course assuming reversal is possible" means the given iterator is a bidirectional one, but that is of course too restrictive! Give me any terminating iteration and I can construct a reversed one other the same elements, don't you think so?

Comment: i partly agree with @Jean-BaptisteYunès because sometimes I need to do something, no matter how unreasonable it is, then its not nice to arrive at an answer that states it is not possible. I partly disagree, because indeed it is not reasonable to make an algortihm copy stuff around when not really needed

Comment: @user463035818: I haven't said it's not possible. **It's not possible in full generality.**

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - I don't. But since it's your last comment, and we bothered poor Bathsheba enough, we can leave it at that.